# Github Action: How to edit a JSON objects with Github repository secrets

Tags: json, github, github-actions, jq

**Github Action: How to edit a JSON object with Github repository secrets** in my workflow I have a job that edits the empty JSON values in JSON file and replaces them with my GitHub secrets. The problem is when I run the `cat 'test.json'` command my updated value does not appear:

JSON file:

```
{
"secret": "",
"name": "test"
}
```

Workflow:

```
steps:
- name: Edit Json
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "`jq '.secret="${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"'test.json`" > test.json
    - name: display
      run: |
        cat 'test.json'
```

Output:

```
{
"secret": "",
"name": "test"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
"secret": "ABCDEFGH",
"name": "test"
}
```

Comment: Try: `jq '.secret = "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"' test.json > test.out.json` and then `cat test.out.json`.

Comment: please consider to use an existing github action to update that value, like https://github.com/jossef/action-set-json-field

Comment: The secret is redacted, it'll never be printed. To test, you could modify it somehow, for example, base64-encode it, and see if the value looks correctly.

Comment: Don't read and write the same file at the same time. The result will almost certainly not be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with `--arg`

This example worked for me:

```
steps:
  - name: Create test file
    run: |
      cat > test.json << EOL
      {
          "secret": "",
          "name": "test"
      }
      EOL
  - name: Edit Json
    shell: bash
    run: |
      echo $(jq --arg a "${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}" '.secret = ($a)' test.json) > test.json   
  - name: display
    run: |
      cat test.json
  - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
      name: my-test-file
      path: ./test.json
```

I used [`actions/upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) so I upload my `test.json` as artifact and then read it on my machine as a workaround as GitHub hides the outputs.

Yes, if you see `***` in the console that doesn't mean that the file didn't change, it's just replaced in the workflows' console & logs.

---

If the secret is not set to your file, check that it's set properly in your repository, then check `jq`'s version on your runners if you use self-hosted ones.

Comment: Another way that worked for me in the end was encrypted the json in repo (gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 /path/to/test.json), and then decrypting that file again when need in the workflow, since you can't store large secrets.